# How to acquire data from users online?

Tags: javascript, web, ftp, html

I prepare to perform a simple project and I don’t know what I should use to accomplish this. I need to receive a data entered by a user (via a webpage) and store them somewhere. I need them to be able to search and returned on the user request. I’m a little old-fashioned so I assumed that should be a file on ftp managed by some python or JS script? I really don’t know where to start so please advise.

[project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSzHB.jpg)

Comment: Involving FTP anywhere in this process seems like a poor and unnecessary idea.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms

Comment: This is why I'm here. I need general advice. Where to store the data? This data should be not visible for all but only as a response to a particular request.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered storing data in a database?
You can use MySQL. It's quite simple after you understand how a database table works.
Data are stored in a table. Table is a part of a database with other tables.
Each table has columns you create. Data are added to the table in rows.
For example, let's say a user sends you their name 'Brian'.
You can have a table called 'users'. In that table, you can create a column 'id' of the user (read about it later, including auto incrementing), and 'name'.
You insert the data into that table. Brian is now in a table with his own ID, like this:

```
id          Name
----------------
1          Brian
```

Check this out:
[SQL tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/)

Comment: Database sounds great because I need data to be related to each other. I know how the database works, I know SQL also, but how to connect everything and where to store and run the database?

Comment: You need a SQL server for this. Which language do you use to code? PHP?

Comment: Currently Python, HTML/CSS, some JS.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't work with Python, so I can't help you with the SQL setting up process. Try looking it up online first. If you don't succeed, ask another question again, but be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution i would recommend:

1. create a mysql server
2. create a backend (links for Java)

   - rest-service https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/
   - access DB https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html
   - put the parts together
3. get/save the data on your webpage with xhr2.